# First excited state of $\rm He$ atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory

The ground state of the Helium atom corresponds to $1s^2$ that in spectroscopic notation can be written as ${}^1S_0$. I'm trying to find the first excited state. It's clear that one electron should be in $n=1$ and  other  in $n=2$. I have no idea, How to go about solving this? I think Hund's law might be useful but don't know, How to go about using it?

Any hint or help is appreciable.

Comment: $1s^2$ corresponds to He or H?? Also, I am interested in how you got the correction formula for He, could you provide a source or derivation or something? My impression was that He fine structure doesn't have a closed form

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy A sorry, There was a big flaw, I edited  the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is straight forward. According to Hfunds rule, the 1st excited state should be $1s^1 2s^1$, so essentially the first excited state is $2s$ whose spectroscopic notation is $2\hspace{1mm} {}^2 S_{1/2}$ if I am not mistaken.

Referring to the question you had preciously put up, strictly speaking LS coupling has to be considered, but its way more complicated since we have two electrons and their two spins, its a coupling considering 4 quantities and is more like a generalized [J-coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-coupling).

Doing a bit of guesswork, I would say it may be approximated as the ordinary LS coupling since the energy difference between $1s$ and $2s$ is significant enough that spin would only split the the level but wont interlace the ordering, with the $l+s$ being lower than $l-s$ (drawing analogy from nuclear coupling).

---

There are two types of nomenclature -

1. [Spectroscopic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopic_notation) - as the name suggests this notation was historically used to denote the various features in the spectra that you observe. The notations like $1s, 2s,...$ are the standard spectroscopic notation, which recently got replaced by lets call "modern" spectroscopic notation which is here you add angular momenta to it. The symbols s,p,d,f takes meaning in this context. Now, in this notation we neglect ground state electrons, for obvious reason which is that they can't get deexcited and doesn't appear in the emission spectra. In our context only the $2s$ guy is excited, so the notation takes into consideration only that.
2. [RS Term Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol) - This is a grand generalization of Spectroscopic Notation which include various couplings and hence kills the very idea of "Spectroscopic Notations" (as in the symbols no longer represent observed spectra but are rather borrowed representation). Based on the comment I assume that you are looking for this particular notation, in which case you consider all electrons, and you get ${}^3S_1$.

Comment: How do you will write the spectroscopic notation for $1s^12s^1$? What you have written seems to be for $1s^22s^1$? Can you verify that it should be ${}^3S_1$?

Comment: @YoungKindaichi it was too long to comment so I have edited my post.